# PhpSpreadsheet - Charts corrupting Excel File

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Here is a simple code to show my problem:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Include the PhpSpreadsheet autoloader

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

// Path file template which includes a chart
$inputFileName = '.../TemplateFile.xlsx';

// Load the spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

// Save the spreadsheet without making any changes
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('.../RetainedFile.xlsx');
?>
```

The template file is loaded, saved as a new file. But the file is corrupted.

In TemplateFile.xlsx are two worksheets and in one worksheet is inserted a chart. When I want to open the file RetainedFile.xlsx, I get the message: "We found a problem with some content in 'RetainedFile.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

I'm using PhpSpreadsheet 1.21.0

Answer (score 0):

PHPSpreedsheet generates a internal copy of the template file. But not all features are implemented (e.g. some diagrams). This can make files corrupt.